# I had a problem with getting datas from Json output

Tags: java, android, json

i was trying to show Json output in my Android app. I'm dropping the site link here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

When i try to show ResponseDTO.java output in AddressPage, it works. But when change it to Address.java or AddressDTO.java, i get null value in my app(in AddressPage)

AddressPage.java:

```
public class AdressPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    String id, usr_name;
    List<Address> userAdressList;
    TextView street, suite, city, zipcode, latText, lngText;
    List<GeoDTO> geoDTOList;
    Float lat, lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_address_page_adapter);
        defVars();
        get_parameters();
        request();
    }

    public void get_parameters() {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = bundle.getString("post_id");
        usr_name = bundle.getString("user_name");
    }

    public void defVars() {
        street = findViewById(R.id.street);
        suite = findViewById(R.id.suite);
        city = findViewById(R.id.city);
        zipcode = findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
        latText = findViewById(R.id.lat);
        lngText = findViewById(R.id.lng);
    }

    public void assignment(List<Address> addresses) {
        street.setText(""+addresses.get(0).getStreet());
        suite.setText(""+addresses.get(0).getSuite());
        city.setText(""+addresses.get(0).getCity());
        zipcode.setText(""+addresses.get(0).getZipcode());

        /*zipcode.setText(id);
        street.setText(id);
        suite.setText(usr_name);
        city.setText(usr_name);*/
    }

    public void request() {
        userAdressList = new ArrayList<>();
        Call<List<Address>> call = ManagerAll.getInstance().managerGetAdress(id, usr_name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Address>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Address>> call, Response<List<Address>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    userAdressList = response.body();
                    assignment(userAdressList);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Address>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

AddressDTO or Address (Same codes):

```
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private String zipcode;
    private Geo geo;
    private String suite;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode){
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getZipcode(){
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setGeo(Geo geo){
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public Geo getGeo(){
        return geo;
    }

    public void setSuite(String suite){
        this.suite = suite;
    }

    public String getSuite(){
        return suite;
    }

    public void setCity(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street){
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getStreet(){
        return street;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "Address{" + 
            "zipcode = '" + zipcode + '\'' + 
            ",geo = '" + geo + '\'' + 
            ",suite = '" + suite + '\'' + 
            ",city = '" + city + '\'' + 
            ",street = '" + street + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

RestApi interface:

```
public interface RestApi {

    @GET("/users")
    Call<List<ResponseDTO>> bring();

    @GET("/users") Call<List<ResponseDTO>> bringResponse(@Query("id")String id, @Query("username")String usr_name);

    @GET("/users") Call<List<Address>> bringAdress(@Query("id")String id, @Query("username")String usr_name);

    //@GET("/users") Call<List<GeoDTO>> bringGeo(@Query("id")String id, @Query("username")String usr_name);

}
```

ManagerAll.java:

```
public class ManagerAll extends BaseManager {

    private static ManagerAll ourInstance = new ManagerAll();

    public static synchronized ManagerAll getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public Call<List<ResponseDTO>> bringCall() {
        Call<List<ResponseDTO>> x = getRestApi().bring();
        return x;
    }

    public Call<List<Address>> managerGetAdress(String post, String username) {
        Call<List<Address>> y = getRestApi().bringAdress(post, username);
        return y;
    }

    public Call<List<ResponseDTO>> managerBringResponse(String post, String username) {
        Call<List<ResponseDTO>> z = getRestApi().bringResponse(post, username);
        return z;
    }

}
```

This is ResponseDTO:

```
public class ResponseDTO implements Serializable {
    private String website;
    private AddressDTO address;
    private String phone;
    private String name;
    private CompanyDTO company;
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String username;

    public void setWebsite(String website){
        this.website = website;
    }

    public String getWebsite(){
        return website;
    }

    public void setAddress(AddressDTO address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public AddressDTO getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setCompany(CompanyDTO company){
        this.company = company;
    }

    public CompanyDTO getCompany(){
        return company;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "ResponseDTO{" + 
            "website = '" + website + '\'' + 
            ",address = '" + address + '\'' + 
            ",phone = '" + phone + '\'' + 
            ",name = '" + name + '\'' + 
            ",company = '" + company + '\'' + 
            ",id = '" + id + '\'' + 
            ",email = '" + email + '\'' + 
            ",username = '" + username + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

As i said, when i set the list in AddressPage AddressDto(or Address) to Response i can get datas. But it gives me null value when i set it to AddressDto.

GeoDTO:

```
public class GeoDTO implements Serializable {
    private String lng;
    private String lat;

    public void setLng(String lng){
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getLng(){
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat){
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLat(){
        return lat;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "GeoDTO{" + 
            "lng = '" + lng + '\'' + 
            ",lat = '" + lat + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

CompanyDTO:

```
public class CompanyDTO implements Serializable {
    private String bs;
    private String catchPhrase;
    private String name;

    public void setBs(String bs){
        this.bs = bs;
    }

    public String getBs(){
        return bs;
    }

    public void setCatchPhrase(String catchPhrase){
        this.catchPhrase = catchPhrase;
    }

    public String getCatchPhrase(){
        return catchPhrase;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "CompanyDTO{" + 
            "bs = '" + bs + '\'' + 
            ",catchPhrase = '" + catchPhrase + '\'' + 
            ",name = '" + name + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

Comment: ResponseDTO  and Address have no same attributes. You can get data from at the middle of json . At first you have to read parent tag then child.

Comment: Like what, can you explain sir? I couldn't get it

Comment: Can you add code of GeoDTO & CompanyDTO?

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Address class is not similar to your json response so you are not getting data from your service . You can read first ResponseDTO data then read address data from json.

Comment: Which lines do i need to change?

Comment: you can not read the json from the middle. you can get address from ResponseDTO  using iteration then you can do what you need

Comment: send you ResponseDTO  response reading code where you can get Address type data